# How can I control, programmatically, the internal digital tv tuner in Android OS Mobile Phones, and Tablets, in unrooted user case?

Tags: android, television, tv-tuner

Like in the title, I like to know how I can control, programmatically, the internal digital tv tuner in Android OS Mobile Phones, and Tablets, like "Motorola Moto E DTV Colors", for example, in unrooted user case. And if I can't control it, then I like to know how I can know, programmatically, the tuned channel in the internal digital tv tuner ..., anytime, in unrooted user case.

Comment: Have you came across this...https://developer.android.com/training/tv/tif/index.html ?

Comment: No. I didn't see it. Thank you so much. I am going to study it and to develop something with it.

Comment: sirvon: I changed this question. By the way, you need to answer it again if you want I accept your answer.